# How to correct the order of execution of code in Swift 5?

Tags: swift5

The code within the function **is executed in a different order** than it is expected. I wanted to change the state of the **login Boolean variable** inside the **if statement**, but the function returns the **initial value** before **if statement is completed**.

> Code sample:

```
class ClassName {

    func loginRequest (name: String, pwd: String) -> Bool {

    var login:Bool
    //Initial value for login
    login = false



    let task = session.uploadTask(with: request, from: jsonData) { data, response, error in

        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            print(httpResponse.statusCode)
            if (httpResponse.statusCode) == 200 {
                //Change the value of login if login is successful
                login = true
                if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {                    
                    do {

                        ...

                    } catch {print(error.localizedDescription)}

                }

            }

        } 

    }
        task.resume()
        //Problem return false in any case because return is completed before if statement
        return login   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [**Completion Handlers**](https://grokswift.com/completion-handler-faqs/) is your friend

*The moment your code runs `task.resume()`, it will run your `uploadTask` and only when that function is finished running it will run the code where you change your `login` variable.*

With That said: That piece of code is running asynchronously. That means your `return login` line of code won't wait for your network request to come back before it runs.

Your code is actually running in the order it should. But i myself wrote my first network call like that and had the same problem. Completion Handles is how i fixed it

---

Here is a very nice tutorial on [**Completion Handlers**](https://grokswift.com/completion-handler-faqs/) or you might know it as [**Callbacks**](https://grokswift.com/completion-handler-faqs/) :

[**Link To Completion Handlers Tutorial**](https://grokswift.com/completion-handler-faqs/)

---

If i can give you a little hint - You will have to change your function so it looks something like this: `func loginRequest (name: String, pwd: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void)`

And replace this `login = true` with `completionHandler(true)`

Wherever it is you call your function it will look something like this:

```
loginRequest(name: String, pwd: String) {didLogIn in
    print("Logged In : \(didLogIn)")
}
```

---

One last thing... You're actually already using Completion Handlers in your code.
`let task = session.uploadTask(with: request, from: jsonData) { data, response, error in 
...` ... But hopefully now you understand a little bit better, and will use a completion handler approach when making network calls.

**GOOD LUCK !**

Comment: No worries. If it doesn't, you can also let me know and i'll try my best to help

Comment: How can we call the segue from within the closure like this: " self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSegue", sender: self) "

Comment: Yes, right after this line `print("Logged In : \(didLogIn)")`... you can call your segue like that.

Comment: It doesn't work, I tried, but it won't. It says that segue can only be called from the main, and when I call it from there "self" does not refer to a button but to closure and should to a button

Comment: have you tried this ?
`DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSegue", sender: self)
        }`

Comment: Feel free to ask me more questions here in the comments when you have any... If i know the answer, i'll definitely share it